# Command Prompt link folder files to another drive and folder like a shortcut

Tags: command-line, copy, file-shortcut

What is the command syntax to link file folder files from one drive to another drive, folder

Example:

Link drives from a full drive C: Documents (all files) to D: Documents (linked back to the C: Documents Folder)

Comment: you want the `mklink` command.  Also note that hard links won't work for this (for files) but symbolic ones will.

Comment: Or junctions (/j). Depends a bit on what you want to do. I often use junctions where possible.

Comment: @LPChip .. me too 100%  :) .. I didn't mention that because he said files.  People rave about Junctions being inferior.. but they are only inferior if used against the network.  Good add though.

Comment: junctions cannot be used against a network anyway.